# Email to user who modified the web-based InfoPath 2007 form

Tags: workflow, infopath, forms-services

May I know how to create a Workflow in a form library that email to the user who modify the form and also CC to a manager? (the manager is a fixed person while the person who modify the form is dynamic - it can be anyone)

Scenario:
A web-based InfoPath form have 1 drop-down field - status. If anyuser in the site make modification to the drop-down field (like changing the status from 'Available' to 'Away'), it will inform that user and CC to a manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create simple workflow using SharePoint Designer.

Your InfoPath form should contain field Manager and you should propagate it to SP when you commit your form. Your workflow can then read this value and use it to sen email to manager. You can use OOTB Modified by (Editor) column to determine person who submitted the form.

Your workflow can be started when item is updated. First you need to check if status condition is met and then you can proceed to mail sending.

Some additional info:

- [Submit form data to a SharePoint library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/submit-form-data-to-a-sharepoint-library-HA010107057.aspx)
- [Send e-mail in a workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx)